How to trigger rerender if the `ref` object has changed
I have the following component :
export function EditTreeContainer<
  T extends TreeTarget<C>,
  C extends TreeContent,
>({
  queryTarget,
  Tree,
  mutations,
}: {
  queryTarget: UseQueryResult<T>;
  Tree: any;
  mutations: {
    article: UseMutationResult<C, Error, any>;
  };
}) {
  const treeRef = useRef<TreeRef<C, TreeNodeData<C>>>(null);
  const [activeNode, setActiveNode] = useState<NodeModel<
    TreeNodeData<C>
  > | null>(null);

  return (
    <div className='flex gap-4 pt-10'>
      <div className='flex h-fit w-full gap-10 rounded-md'>
        <Tree
          ref={treeRef}
          queryTarget={queryTarget}
          draggable={true}
          editable={true}
          mutate={true}
          onClick={(node: NodeModel<TreeNodeData<C>>) => setActiveNode(node)}
          className='w-[400px]'
        />
        <div className='max-w-[800px] flex-1'>
          {activeNode && (
            <DefaultTreeContentBox
              content={activeNode.data.content}
              options={{
                edit: {
                  enabled: true,
                  mutations: mutations,
                },
              }}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

treeRef contains some states and state setters that are defined in Tree (using useImperativeHandle). One of such a states is activeNode. The problem is that if I pass treeRef to DefaultTreeContentBox (which now is not the case), and inside of this component I will use treeRef.current.activeNode, then if in the tree I use treeRef.current.setActiveNode then the DefaultTreeContentBox will not rerender. How to force it to rerender? In the code I attached I started to define states outside of Tree but I would prefer to keep all the states in Tree and only access them from ref.

Piece of advice: I would not recommend to trigger rerenders to achieve some logic, probably it means that could be solved in another way
Mmmm if you want it in that way yesoryes, you can use an useEffect
useEffect(() => {}, [treeRef.current])

// here be careful if it's an object because it could rerender in an infinite loop
// try to be very specific in the property that you want to evaluate as a dependency
// compare the object with lodash or as a final option use JSON.stringify
like [_.isEqual(treeRef.current.activeNode)] or [JSON.stringify(treeRef.current.activeNode)]

